# text-overflow: ellipsis is displaying different character

Tags: css

I've got a bit of a CSS problem here.

[See this image](https://www.flickr.com/photos/125543025@N07/?saved=1)

In this image I added CSS styles for the text "INTENSE TRAINING"

```
.sample-style{ 
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden !important;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap; }
```

The problem is when I add

```
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

It displays that big O with 2 dots on top instead of "...".
Can anyone tell me what is going on here? I tried this code with my other project and it works.

This is my markup:

```
<div class="panel radius panel-click">
  <a href="#" data-dropdown="drop1" class="tiny right dropdown" data-options="align:left;"><i class="fi-wrench"></i></a>
  <div class="large-12">
    <h1 class="panel-title text-upper"><small>INTENSE TRAINING</small></h1>
  </div>    
  <div class="large-12">
    <h2><small>train with the champ</small></h2>
  </div>
  <div class="large-12">
    <img src="image.jpg" alt="this is an image">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just tried it in jsfiddle and your code works fine by itself.

Comment: That is just weird. btw, I'm using Foundation 5 as my framework. just wondering if it does have anything to do with it or not?

Comment: @Ashenvale Do you remember how did you solve it? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow which tells you:

> This keyword value indicates to display an ellipsis ('…', U+2026 HORIZONTAL ELLIPSIS) to >represent clipped text.

Which means that both your [declared charset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta) and [font](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2026/fontsupport.htm) should support the `U+2026` for a proper display.

Notice that authors are encouraged to use UTF-8.

So please verify that your problem the problem still exists when you change your charset to `utf-8` and use a font that support `U+2026`.

The [text-overflow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow) property also accepts a string instead of the `ellipsis` but this (experimental) syntax can only be use for Firefox.