# CSS3 Ellipsis cuts on string ending on different characters

Tags: html, css, less

I have following CSS Code;

Same issue was reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24305535/text-overflow-ellipsis-is-displaying-different-character) in different question but no has answered it.

```
span {
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    white-space: nowrap\9;
    overflow: hidden\9;
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: normal;
    width: 83%;
    width: -webkit-calc(100% - 65px);
    width: calc(100% - 65px);
    width: -moz-calc(100% - 65px);
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<h1><span>ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ</span></h1>
```

Screenshot is also added as well, demonstrating problem.
[image]

Comment: It works well for me http://jsfiddle.net/3fLat6df/

Answer (score 1):

At https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow you can read:

> ellipsis This keyword value indicates to display an ellipsis ('…',
>   U+2026 HORIZONTAL ELLIPSIS) to represent clipped text. The ellipsis is
>   displayed inside the content area, decreasing the amount of text
>   displayed. If there is not enough space to display the ellipsis, **it is
>   clipped**.

So i expect that your ellipsis has been clipped (not enough space due to your string do not have spaces). For that reason i also think that [text-overflow: ellipsis is displaying different character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24305535/text-overflow-ellipsis-is-displaying-different-character) describes a different issue.