# Whenever I use "ellipsis" for text wrapping, random characters show up? (Is it a charset problem?)

Tags: javascript, html, css, cytoscape.js, cytoscape

I am trying to wrap a text and put '...' after some length on my Cytoscape graph labels. I have this code:

```js
style: [{
  selector: 'node',
  css: {
    'label': 'data(id)',
    'text-wrap': 'ellipsis',
    'text-max-width': 10,
    'text-justification': 'left',
    'font-family': 'serif',
    'color': 'red'
  }
}]
```

However when I do this, random characters show up instead of the original text.
There was a similar question on Stack Overflow: [text-overflow: ellipsis is displaying different character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24305535/text-overflow-ellipsis-is-displaying-different-character)

In here, the accepted answer tells that the charset has to be utf-8 and the font should be supported by U+2026.

Thus I put this tag in my HTML:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

And my font family is serif, so I do not know what can solve the problem.
PS: This is the documentation that tells how to use Cytoscape text wrapping: https://js.cytoscape.org/#style/labels And I was able to wrap the text using the `wrap` option instead of `ellipsis` thus I do not think the code structure is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You can prevent this by using a function to calculate your labels. In the cytoscape.js stylesheet, you can do something like this:

```
style: [
    {
      selector: "node",
      css: {
        'label': function(node) {
            if (node.data("name").length > 20) {  
                return `${node.data("name").substring(0, 20)}...`;
            else {
                return ${node.data("name");
            }
        },
        height: "60px",
        width: "60px"
      }
    },
    ...
```

In the code snippet, I used the ellipsis property and got no errors:

```js
var cy = (window.cy = cytoscape({
  container: document.getElementById("cy"),

  boxSelectionEnabled: false,
  autounselectify: true,

  style: [{
      selector: "node",
      css: {
        content: "data(name)",
        height: "60px",
        width: "60px"
      }
    },
    {
      selector: "edge",
      css: {
        "target-arrow-shape": "triangle"
      }
    },
    {
      selector: ".multiline-manual",
      style: {
        "text-wrap": "wrap"
      }
    },

    {
      selector: ".multiline-auto",
      style: {
        "text-wrap": "ellipsis",
        "text-max-width": 120
      }
    }
  ],

  elements: {
    nodes: [{
        data: {
          id: "n0",
          name: "This is a very long name and all I have to do is to add a class!"
        },
        classes: "multiline-auto"
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: "n1",
          name: "Shorter Text----------"
        },
        classes: "multiline-auto"
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: "n2",
          name: "This shouldn't wrap"
        },
        classes: "multiline-manual"
      },
      {
        data: {
          id: "n3",
          name: "This should\nwrap"
        },
        classes: "multiline-manual"
      }
    ],
    edges: [{
        data: {
          source: "n0",
          target: "n1"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          source: "n1",
          target: "n2"
        }
      },
      {
        data: {
          source: "n1",
          target: "n3"
        }
      }
    ]
  },

  layout: {
    name: "dagre",
    padding: 5
  }
}));

console.log(cy.nodes())
```

```css
body {
  font: 14px helvetica neue, helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
}

#cy {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  float: left;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset=utf-8 />
  <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimal-ui">
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/cytoscape@3.3.0/dist/cytoscape.min.js">
  </script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/jquery@3.3.1/dist/jquery.js"></script>
  <!-- cyposcape dagre -->
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/dagre@0.7.4/dist/dagre.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js-dagre/1.5.0/cytoscape-dagre.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="cy"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Do you happen to know how to use "text-overflow-wrap" in order to wrap the texts that don't have new lines?

Comment: The style `"text-wrap": "wrap", "text-max-width": 80` already does that. You don't need "text-overflow-wrap" for that. Node n0 uses the multiline-auto class and its name is just a long string, no \n needed.

Comment: But doesn't documentatıon say that, "text-wrap" works for strings which contains newlines and spaces?

Comment: I think I get your question now. If you are using the correct syntax for labels (which you probalby are), then the problem is harder for me to reproduce. Can you post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in your original question which produced your error? You can use some of my code as a base if you'd like.